# Why does my inputfield close when I click the other checkbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why does my `InputField` close when I click the `Livestream` and then click other checkbox.
What I did here is create a `state` wherein when the users click the livestream, It will open the `AppointmentForm`, `AppointmentForm` is just an input so i didn't include it. I'm using `Shadcn`

Appointment.tsx

```
const [openWebinar, setOpenWebinar] = useState(false);

<CheckboxAppointmentFormService
  control={form.control}
  name="meetingWebinar"
  data={webinarFeatures}
  label="Zoom Webinar"
  inputDataService={openWebinar}
  setInputDataService={setOpenWebinar}
  inputName="meetingWebinarLivestream"
  inputPlaceholder="Link"
  inputType="text"
  inputAssitance="Link"
/>;
```

CheckboxAppointmentFormService.tsx

```
export default function CheckboxAppointmentFormService({
    control,
    name,
    label,
    data,
    inputDataService,
    setInputDataService,
    inputName,
    inputPlaceholder,
    inputType,
    inputAssitance
} : CheckboxAppointmentFormProps) {
  return (
    <FormField
    control={control}
    name={name}
    render={() => (
      <FormItem>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <FormLabel className="text-base">
            {label}
          </FormLabel>
        </div>

        {data.map((item) => (
          <FormField
            key={item.id}
            control={control}
            name="items"
            render={({ field }) => {
              return (
                <FormItem
                  key={item.id}
                  className="flex flex-row items-start space-x-3 space-y-0"
                >
                  <FormControl>
                    <Checkbox
                      checked={field.value?.includes(item.id)}
                      onCheckedChange={(checked) => {
                        if (Array.isArray(field.value)) {
                          field.onChange(
                            checked
                              ? [...field.value, item.id]
                              : field.value.filter(
                                  (value) => value !== item.id
                                )
                          );
                        } else {
                        
                          field.onChange(
                            checked ? [item.id] : []
                          );
                        }
                        setInputDataService(
                          checked && item.id === "6" 
                        );
                      }}
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormLabel className="text-sm font-normal">
                    {item.label}
                  </FormLabel>
                </FormItem>
              );
            }}
          />
        ))}

        {inputDataService && (
           <AppointmentForm
           name={inputName}
           placeholder={inputPlaceholder}
           type={inputType}
           label={inputAssitance}
           control={control}
         />
        )}


        <FormMessage />
      </FormItem>
    )}
  />
  )
}
```

This is my data

```
export const webinarFeatures = [
  {id: '1', label: "Practice Sessions"},
  {id: '2', label: "Reminder Email"},
  {id: '3', label: "Recording"},
  {id: '4', label: "Poll"},
  {id: '5', label: "Q&A Box"},
  {id: '7', label: "Panelist"},
  {id: '6', label: 'Livestreaming'}
]
```

For example. Click the `Livestreaming`

[image]

The inputfield open, but when I  click other `checkbox`, the inputfield closes.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm all over @James Ashok's statement and you can fix it by checking whether the item id is "6" before updating the state as follows

```js
if (item.id === "6"){
    setInputDataService(checked);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue lies on `onCheckedChange` callback where you are calling `setInputDataService(checked && item.id === "6");` and you have this callback in a loop (`data.map((item) => {})`) which means this callback is mapped for each checkbox that is rendered..

So, first time you enable `Livestreaming` it enables your Appointment form because it reaches your `onCheckedChange` of `Livestreaming` checkbox.

Next time, when you enable other checkbox, it executes the `onCheckedChange` of that checkbox whose id is not 6. So, it executes `setInputDataService(false)` thereby removing your Appointment form from the DOM.

To fix this, instead of `item.id === "6"` find a way to check if `6` (Livestreaming id) is present in the checkbox field array of selected values.